# Compiler and Parser , wrong answer on codechef

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

You can find the question on below link
https://www.codechef.com/problems/COMPILER
I want to solve this question by using Stack Structure only and not in any other simple way .
I have checked the output for upto all possible 6 character length inputs but cannot find any wrong answer (I compared the ouptut from the correct solution)
Please find any combination for which the algo will give wrong answer.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def isempty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()
    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
for j in range(int(input())):
    arr=[x for x in input()]
    s=Stack()
    balanced=True
    answer=0
    fanswer=0
    for h in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[h]=="<":
            s.push("<")
        else:
            if s.isempty():

                break
            else:
                s.pop()
                if not s.isempty():
                    balanced=False
                    answer=answer+1
                else:
                    balanced=True
                    fanswer=fanswer+1


                if h==(len(arr)-1) and s.isempty()!=True:
                    answer=0
    if balanced==False: answer=0                
    print((answer+fanswer)*2)
```

EDIT: I used two variables to store answer 
Consider the cases '<><' and '<<><'

Comment: "_Please find any combination_" is not a question, and is definitely off topic on SO.

Comment: Your `Stack` does not do more than a normal `list`. All operations are supported in lists, just with other names. Some are even more simple.

Comment: One problem you'll run into is stack overflow. Expressions can be up to 10^6 characters in length. If one of those expressions has, say, 499,999 "<" characters followed by 499,999 ">" characters, you're going to run out of stack space because it will take at least 1 megabyte of stack to push all those "<" characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the expression `<<>><<>`.

When you get to the second `>` character, `answer` is equal to 1, and `fanswer` is equal to 1. The expression is balanced up to the 4th character.

When you get to the last `>`, you increment `answer`, but then you encounter this:

```
if h==(len(arr)-1) and s.isempty()!=True:
    answer=0
```

So you set `answer` to 0 because you're at the end of the string and the stack isn't empty. The result, then, is that `(answer+fanswer)*2` returns 2, which is incorrect. The correct answer is 4.

You can simplify your code quite a bit by just keeping track of the last index at which the expression was balanced. The general idea is below. Note that it's not exactly Python code, but you should be able to convert easily enough.

```
balancePos = -1

for n in range(arr)
    if (arr[n] == "<")
        stack.push("<")
    else
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            break;
        stack.pop()
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            balancePos = n
print(balancePos+1)
```

By the way, I know you said that you want to do this using a stack, but there's really no reason to use one. You can do it with a simple counter that you initialize to 0. Replace every `stack.push` with a counter increment, and every `stack.pop` with a decrement. And `if (stack.isEmpty())` becomes `if (counter == 0)`.

That eliminates the potential for stack overflow, and will be quite a bit faster, too.